# UDF for adding array columns in spark scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**We have a requirement to add the sum and ratio as below.**

```
Input File:Array(Array("a:25","a:30","b:30"),Array("a:25","a:30","b:30"))
```

**we need the output to be ratios:**

```
step 1:
=======
a:25+30+25+30  ==> a:110
b:30 + 30      ==> b:60

step 2:
=======
a=a/a+b  ==>a:110/170
b=b/a+b ==>b:60/170
```

So far I tried This:

```
val a = Array(Array("a:25","a:30","b:30"),Array("a:25","a:30","b:30"))
val res=a.flatMap(a=>a.map(x=>x.split(":")))
val res1=res.map(y => (y(0).asInstanceOf[String],(y(1).toDouble.asInstanceOf[Double]))).groupBy(_._1).map(x=>(x._1, x._2.map(_._2).sum)).toArray
```

**Input File or Dataframe:**

```
 [54,WrappedArray(
    [WrappedArray(BCD001:10.0, BCD006:20.0),
    WrappedArray(BCD003:10.0, BCD006:30.0)],
    [WrappedArray(BCD005:50.0, BCD006:10.0),
    WrappedArray(BCD003:70.0, BCD006:0.0)])]

ouput file or dataframe: after 
adding all the BCD code values and ratios per bcd

eg. in record1 sum = 10+20+10+30+50+10+70+0= 210
ratio per BCD code = 10/210 = 0.50`
```

---

### **output file:**

```
[54,WrappedArray([BCD001:0.5,
BCD006:0.1,BCD003:0.4,BCD005:0.25])]
```

Comment: what does this have to do with spark?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Actually we have wrappedArray with similar data we need to write a UDF to achieve the above requirement.

Comment: could you please give an example how your rdd or dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your data structure is not like sequence of sequences

```
val a = Array(Array("a:25","a:30","b:30"),Array("a:25","a:30","b:30"))
```

but more like a Sequence of tuple of sequence (you can verify with printSchema in spark)

```
val a = Seq((Seq("BCD001:10.0", "BCD006:20.0"),Seq("BCD003:10.0", "BCD006:30.0")),
  (Seq("BCD005:50.0", "BCD006:10.0"),Seq("BCD003:70.0", "BCD006:0.0")))
```

in which case you need something like:

```
def parse(sq:Seq[String])=sq.map(x=>{val y=x.split(":")
  (y.head,y.last.toDouble)})
val res=a.flatMap(a=>Seq(parse(a._1),parse(a._2))).flatten.groupBy{case (k,_)=>k}
  .map{case (k,vs)=>(k,vs.foldLeft(0.0){case (t,(_,v))=>t+v})}
val tot=res.values.sum
res.map{case (k,v)=> s"$k:${v/tot}"}.toArray
```

resulting in:

```
res0: Array[String] = Array(BCD006:0.3, BCD003:0.4, BCD005:0.25, BCD001:0.05)
```

Comment: Input File or Dataframe:
---------------------
[54,WrappedArray(
[WrappedArray(BCD001:10.0, BCD006:20.0),
WrappedArray(BCD003:10.0, BCD006:30.0)],
[WrappedArray(BCD005:50.0, BCD006:10.0),
WrappedArray(BCD003:70.0, BCD006:0.0)])]

ouput file or dataframe: after 
adding all the BCD code values and ratios per bcd

eg. in record1 sum = 10+20+10+30+50+10+70+0= 210
ratio per BCD code = 10/210 = 0.50
-------------
output file:
-------------
[54,WrappedArray([BCD001:0.5,
BCD006:0.1,BCD003:0.4,BCD005:0.25])]`

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean

Comment: updated the requirement with input and output dataframes

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
val a = Array(Array("a:25","a:30","b:30"),Array("a:25","a:30","b:30"))

val res = a.flatMap(a=>a.map(x=>{
  val splitted = x.split(":")
  (splitted(0).trim, splitted(1).trim.toInt)
}))
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .map(x => (x._1, x._2.map(_._2).sum))

val total = res.values.sum

res.map(x => (x._1, x._2+"/"+total))
  .foreach(println)
```

which should give you

```
(b,60/170)
(a,110/170)
```

If you don't want the string values you can do

```
res.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toDouble/total))
  .foreach(println)
```

which should give

```
(b,0.35294117647058826)
(a,0.6470588235294118)
```